# Clojure eval error

Tags: clojure

Using Clojure 1.2, this code works

```
(defn A [] (fn [a] (+ a 2)))
(println ((A) 0))
(println (eval (list (A) 0)))
```

but the following code fails on the third line

```
(defn A [b] (fn [a] (+ a b)))
(println ((A 3) 0))
(println (eval (list (A 3) 0)))
```

Why?

Comment: do you have a pressing need to use Clojure 1.2? 1.4 is a lot better? fortunately the answer to this question is version agnostic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `(list (A 3))` returns a function in a list:

```
user> (list (A 3) 0)
(#<user$A$fn__2934 user$A$fn__2934@2f09b4cb> 0)
```

`eval` expects to get a symbol in a list and it was getting the function it's self. if you quote the call to `(A 3)` then you will get the result you seek

```
user> (println (eval (list '(A 3) 0)))
3
nil
```

Part of this code is being evaluated before the call to `eval` and then `eval` is evaluating the rest. It is more common to se eval used on quoted forms with perhaps a term or
to selectively unquoted (`~`).

```
user> (eval '((A 3) 0))
3
```

or

```
user> (def my-number 3)
#'user/my-number
user> (eval `((A ~my-number) 0))
3
```

edit: on the question of why it works with zero args and fails with one arg:

it seems that both forms work if you don't store them in vars (ie define them with defn)
and instead manually inline them:

```
user> (def A (fn [b] (fn [a] (+ a b))))
#'user/A
user> (eval (list (A 3) 0))
; Evaluation aborted.
user> (eval (list (fn [b] (fn [a] (+ a b)) 3) 0))
3
```

Comment: Thanks.  If eval is passed a function as the first argument in the list, why is .toString called?  Also, why does the first example work, even though it lacked such a quote?

Comment: I was totally wrong on the .toString part. I was testing in the repl and printing the intermediate stage and reading it back (which produces a different error)

Comment: im still looking into that last part

Comment: Using quotes helped for this specific example, but I still ran into a bit of trouble with some more general things I was attempting to do.  Turns out, I actually should have been using "apply" (not "eval") to get the behavior I was expecting.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I have yet to see a situation where I actually needed to use eval in one of my programs. Often I think I do and then find some better way.